# Unable to get mail() to work on WAMP Server

Tags: php, windows, email, wamp, sendmail

I've looked around quite a bit on this and while I've found many sites describing how to do it, I am still unable to send mail from a Windows 8 (64-bit) VM using WAMP and sendmail.exe. I have checked the settings in sendmail.ini and php.ini and according to what I've read, I am all set to go:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
; SMTP = mail.yourdomain.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
; smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
; sendmail_from = you@yourdomain.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
sendmail_path = C:\wamp\bin\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not a Wamp user but I don't think that Windows qualifies as Unix :-?

Comment: I know, and yet this is the same advice I see in all the articles I've found.

Comment: Alright, it must be some hack by the Wamp Server devs. Whatever, how are you testing this and what exact problem are you facing? "Does not work" is as vague and generic as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Egg on my face on this one. Thanks Alvaro. I was so intent on following the articles I just didn't think to use the Win32, especially since they say Win32 Only.

Duh on me. Problem solved:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
 SMTP = mail.yourdomain.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
 smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
 sendmail_from = you@yourdomain.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
```